# Exception- java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to custom object while converting a JSON List to Java objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Facade pattern to implement JSON conversion. I have POJO classes corresponding to multiple JSON structures. I have facade classes corresponding to each POJO class. There is an AbstractFacade which has the implementation for converting the JSON entries to Java objects.

So, here is an example :

books.json

```
     [
      {
        category : "self-help",
        count :268         
       },
       {
        category : "fiction",
        count :268         
        }  
    ]
```

Book.java

```
 public class Book {

          private String category;
          private int count;

          //getters and setters
 }
```

BookFacade.java

```
public class BookFacade extends AbstractFacade<Book> {
    public BookFacade() {
        super(Book.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

@Override
public ArrayList<Book> readFileOfObjectList(String filePath){
    try {
        return super.readFileOfObjectList(filePath);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;


    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
  }     
}
```

AbstractFacade.java

```
public class AbstractFacade<T> implements JSONFileUtil{

private  Class<T> entityClass;

public Class<T> getEntityClass() {
    return entityClass;
}

public void setEntityClass(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    super();
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

class ListT extends ArrayList<T>{

}

@Override
public ListT readFileOfObjectList(String fileName) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ListT list=mapper.readValue(new File(fileName), new TypeReference<ListT>(){});
    System.out.println("In abstract facade:"+list.get(0).getClass().getName());
    return list;
}



@Override
public void writeFile(String fileName, Object data) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

So, I create an object of BookFacade in my main program and calls the method `readFileOfObjectList`. I get an ArrayList, but the objects within it are of type LinkedHashMap. I have checked many answers in StackOverflow. But none of them works for me. Could you please help?

Comment: I assume you are using jackson (2.x), is that correct?

Comment: No, jackson-mapper-asl version is 1.8.5